# DownloadManager enqueue queue file and keeps on downloading in Oreo and above

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-download-manager, android-9.0-pie

I am using DownloadManager to download pdf file in my application. In devices with OS version of Oreo and above, the file is queued for download and keeps on downloading. But after some time nothing happens and no error or exception is shown. The same works fine in the device of OS version below Oreo.

Below is the code used.

```
     private void startDownload(String downloadPath, String destinationPath) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(downloadPath); // Path where you want to download file.

            File destinationFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder_name");
            destinationFile.mkdir();
            destinationFile = new File(destinationFile.getAbsolutePath(), "file_name.pdf");

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);  // Tell on which network you want to download file.
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);  // This will show notification on top when downloading the file.
            request.setTitle("Downloading a file"); // Title for notification.
            request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
            request.setDestinationUri(destinationFile);  // Storage directory path

            ((DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE)).enqueue(request); // This will start downloading 
        }
```

Have enabled required permissions and tried setting Network type as well but no luck. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to set fileprovider. its just a rough guess, without seeing your code it is difficult.

Comment: you might need a network security configuration, in case the source is `HTTP`.

Comment: Have shared the code used in the application.